# ugly CSS source Code; Is there any way to reformat the code with Dreamweaver / Aptana?

Tags: css, coding-style, dreamweaver, reformat

I have a bit questions regarding the way we do "Coding CSS".

Probably because I'm a java programmer which is used to interact with Netbeans,
I love the way it format the code works...

Just Pressing the Keyboard Shorcut( ALT + SHIFT + F), all your ugly code become formatted, aligned, and nicely.

And now... when I deal with CSS inside Dreamweaver CS5....
I didn't see this kind of ShortCut (or actions). Especially when I have to
dive into some CSS file. Look [at this preview link here](http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/3310/uglycss.jpg).

COrrect me if i'm wrong. I dont think Dreamweaver have it.
Or should I switch to Aptana... for obtaining this feature?

Hmmm.... But how to reformat the code in Dreamweaver to be nicely,
as Netbeans Does reformatting the code anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit [Adobe Dreamweaver CS5 & CS5.5 * Format CSS code](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WS6A10E93F-6587-4e1b-956C-03CBD7F678BBa.html). It seems to cover what you are after.